# How to display parent table columns in django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have two models in django as below:

```
class Directorates(models.Model):
  entrydate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  directoratename = models.CharField("Directorate", max_length=1000)
  note = models.CharField("Note", max_length=2000, null=True)
  insertedby = models.IntegerField(null=False)
  updatedby = models.IntegerField(null=False, default='0')
  deletedby = models.IntegerField(null=False, default='0')

  def __str__(self):
    return self.directoratename


class Departments(models.Model):
  entrydate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  departmentname = models.CharField("Department", max_length=1000)
  note = models.CharField("Note", max_length=2000, null=True)
  directorate = models.ForeignKey(Directorates, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  insertedby = models.IntegerField(null=False)
  updatedby = models.IntegerField(null=False, default='0')
  deletedby = models.IntegerField(null=False, default='0')

  def __str__(self):
    return self.departmentname
```

What I want to do is to display id, departmentname, note from Departments model and directoratename from Directorates model in a table in template.

Below is my query which needs to be edited to meet the requirements.

```
 Departments.objects.filter(deletedby=0).values("id", "departmentname", "note", "directorate_id").order_by('-id')[:5]
```

Below is the code for table population.

```
{% for d in data %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ d.departmentname }}</td>
    <td>directoratename to be displayed here.....</td>
    <td>{{ d.note }}</td>
    <td class="pull-right">
      <form action="{% url 'app:departments-delete' d.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
          <a href="{% url 'app:departments-edit' d.id %}" class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></a>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I searched google to find the solution for this however I couldn't find any solution for this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making things harder for yourself by using a `values()` query. Just pass the objects themselves:

```
departments = Departments.objects.filter(deletedby=0)
```

and now you can do:

```
{% for d in data %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ d.departmentname }}</td>
    <td>{{ d.directorate.directoratename }}</td>
```

Note that you can make this more efficient by using `select_related` in the original query:

```
departments = Departments.objects.filter(deletedby=0).select_related('directorate')
```

Also note that it is normal in Django to give the models singular names - Department, Directorate - because an instance refers to a single one.